# Plot Plotly Values in Ascending Order

Tags: r, dplyr, plotly, bar-chart, r-plotly

I have a dataset, data, with the following values:

```
   ID                TIME                         Duration   
    A                12/18/2019 4:45:10 AM        1 sec
    A                12/18/2019 9:06:59 PM        0 sec                    
    B                12/19/2019 4:14:13 AM        7 sec
    B                12/19/2019 4:14:20 AM        0 sec
    A                12/18/2019 4:45:11 AM        0 sec
```

```
 p <- plot_ly(data = df,
        x = ~ID,
        y = ~Duration,
        name = "Title",
        type = "bar",
        orientation = 'v',
        order = "ascending"

     )%>% 
layout(
       title = "Title",
       xaxis = list(title = "ID", tickangle = -45 ),
       yaxis = list(title = "Time In Seconds"))
```

How would I specify that the graph is in ascending order like the picture below. 
categoryorder = 'ascending" is not working.

[image]

Comment: Regarding the error you mentioned, You should provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can check and reproduce the error and debug it. Instead of copy/pasting your data, please use `dput(head(df,5))` and [edit] your question by adding output of that. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `reorder` to set the levels of `ID` which is a factor to be set based on `Duration` values.

```r
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Dur.order = sum(as.numeric(Duration))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(ID.order = reorder(ID, Dur.order)) %>% 
plot_ly(data = .,
             x = ~ID.order,
             y = ~Duration,
             name = "Title",
             type = "bar",
             orientation = 'v',
             order = "ascending") %>% 
  layout(title = "Title",
         xaxis = list(title = "ID", tickangle = -45 ),
         yaxis = list(title = "Time In Seconds"))
```

[image]

***Data:***

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A"), 
                      Date = c("12/18/2019 4:45:10 AM", "12/18/2019 9:06:59 PM", 
                               "12/19/2019 4:14:13 AM", "12/19/2019 4:14:20 AM", 
                               "12/18/2019 4:45:11 AM"), 
                      Duration = structure(c(1, 0, 7,0 , 0), 
                 class = "difftime", units = "secs")), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Ok I will try this. Thank you. Is there a way to also associate the Time with the ID on the chart. (So we know the time period in which these events took place)?

Comment: ok thank you. I am also getting this error: 'bar' objects don't have these attributes: 'order'